# BlocBuilder cannot listen to all state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm practicing with **flutter bloc** and I'm getting used to using `BlocBuilder`. I understand it can listen to all `state` changes and I can update widgets easily. Everything was going well until I hit the `emit state` twice in a row and I ran into a problem.

I `emit state` several times in a row, and I only get the last `state` in `BlocBuilder`, which is completely different from what I expected.

Below is the code of my **bloc.dart**:

```dart
   emit(state.copyWith(testText: "1"));
   emit(state.copyWith(testText: "2"));
   emit(state.copyWith(testText: "3"));
   emit(state.copyWith(testText: "4"));
```

1. Use `BlocBuilder` to listen to the `state`:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TestBloc, TestState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.testText != current.testText,
      builder: (context, state) {
        print("state.testText builder>>> ${state.testText}");
        return Center();
      },
    );
  }
```

The result of the output. I expected to get 1, 2, 3, 4, but only 4.

```sh
flutter: state.testText builder>>> 4
```

2. Use `BlocConsumer` to listen to the `state`:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<TestBloc, TestState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous.testText != current.testText,
      listener: (context, state) {
        print("state.testText listener >>> ${state.testText}");
      },
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.testText != current.testText,
      builder: (context, state) {
        print("state.testText builder>>> ${state.testText}");
        return Center();
      },
    );
  }
```

The result of the output. The `listener` fully meets my expectations, but this is different from what I understand. The `listener` I understand is only responsible for updating loading, dialog, etc.

```sh
flutter: state.testText listener >>> 1
flutter: state.testText listener >>> 2
flutter: state.testText listener >>> 3
flutter: state.testText listener >>> 4
flutter: state.testText builder>>> 4
```

I wonder why `BlocBuilder` can't listen to all state? When to use `BlocBuilder` and when to use `BlocListener`? In order not to miss state, do I need to replace it with `BlocListener`?

Is `BlocBuilder` optimized? In order to avoid building widgets frequently, is the `state` obtained only once per runloop?

Answer (score 1):

Please add await 100 milliseconds between emit methods.

Maybe you're changing the state too quickly. Maybe you're changing the situation too quickly.
If Flutter draws the screen in 1 ms, you are changing the state from 1 to 4 in 0.5ms. you are changing the state from 1 to 4 in 0.5 ms.

Comment: The actual situation will not call `emit` continuously, usually `await` a `future`. But if this `future` comes back so fast that `BlocBuilder` doesn't perceive it.